# Onboard command causing bash script to stop

Tags: bash, xubuntu, onboard

I try to write a little bash script for my mothers laptop with xubuntu. The problem she have is after every version update of xubuntu the keyboard isn't working anymore. I also had this problem on any laptop i installed xubuntu. To help her solve this problem by her self i wanted to write a small script.

```
#!/bin/bash
xfce4-terminal -e "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration" &
onboard
wait
killall onboard
exit 0
```

This should open the keyboard reconfiguration assistant and the onboard keyboard for navigating and enter sudo password.

If i run it with bash -x i get this output:

```
bash -x testrun
+ onboard
+ xfce4-terminal -e 'sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration'
21:36:42.063 WARNING Config: mousetweaks GSettings schema not found, mousetweaks integration disabled.
```

So it seems like the script stops after executing the onboard command.

How can i avoid this? Or is there any better solution than reconfiguration for this problem?

Thx for help
greetings

Answer (score 0):

So managed now to get it work

```
#!/bin/bash
#filename=testrun
script_name=$0
script_full_path=$(dirname "$0")

$script_full_path/onboard_run &
xfce4-terminal -e "sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration" &

while pgrep -x "xfce4-terminal" > /dev/null
do
    sleep 0.5
done

killall onboard
killall testrun
exit 0

#!/bin/bash
#filename=onboard_run
onboard
exit 0
```

But this is just very inefficient to use two scripts to run two commands...